# Why I need to start/bind my service in test case even though the service is running in background

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-service, android-testing

In my Android project I have an **Activity**:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity{
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class)
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

In `onStart()` of `MyActivity`, I just starts `MyService`.

My simple **service** is just used to listen to **phone state change**:

```
public MyService extends Service{
  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int arg, int id) {
       super.onStartCommand(intent, arg, id);
       /*register a PhoneStateListener to TelephonyManager*/
       startToListenToPhoneState();// show Toast message for phone state change
       return START_STICKY;
  }
}
```

Everything works fine, after launch my app, when I make a phone call, my service is listening to phone state change & show toast messages.

**NEXT**, I decide to unit test my project, so I created a `AndroidTestCase` in my test project:

```
public class MySimpleTest extends AndroidTestCase{
   ...
   @Override
   protected void runTest() {
      //make a phone call
      String url = "tel:3333";
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
      mContext.startActivity(mIntent);
   }
}
```

The above test case simply starts a phone call, and it works fine too.

I press the HOME button to bring my app to background, after which, I run the test case to start a phone call, I was expecting that the `PhoneStateListener` in my service would still be running to show me the Toast message, **but it didn't**.

Then I figured out that I have to either **start** or **bind** `MyService` in my test case too, after which I am able to see the toast message from PhoneStateListener when run my test case, **Why is that?** I mean **Why my service is running in background with my app but I still have to start or bind the service in test case** in order to trigger the PhoneStateLister defined in `MyService` when running a `AndroidTestCase`?

Answer (score 0):

In Android ServiceTestCase documentation, it says,

> The test case waits to call onCreate() until one of your test methods calls startService(Intent) or bindService(Intent). This gives you an opportunity to set up or adjust any additional framework or test logic before you test the running service.

I think AndroidTestCase provides a framework which you can test your activities, services and so on in a controlled environment so that you should at least start your service before you test interacting with your service.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ServiceTestCase.html

Comment: Hi，but I am not using ServiceTestCase, I am using AndroidTestCase

Comment: You need to think about the purpose of using AndroidTestCase. In your test program, you are not testing anything, but just making a phone call. You need to load a new instance of the application under test, which means you should start a service from your test case. I recommend you to read this Testing Fundamentals: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html